# Fetching Guild Categories

Tags: python, discord.py

I am attempting to fetch all of the guild's categories and list each channel inside of the category.

Is it something like this?

```py
for category in ctx.guild.categories
    for channel in category.channels:
        print(channel.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you wish to confirm this, you can review the `discord.py` documentation for [Guild.categories](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.channels) and [CategoryChannel.channels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.channels), or try running your own code.